# CASE when using data from a table not in a join

Tags: sql, sql-server

What I am trying to do is to check whether a different table (on a different server) has the data related to exchangerate for the month when the ETA is due.

This is the code:

```
SELECT distinct 
case when month(pod_eta)>month(getdate()) AND month(max(server.database.[dbo].[CustomsExchangeRate].validto))> month(getdate()) then pod_eta 
    when month(pod_eta)>month(getdate()) AND month(max(server.database.[dbo].[CustomsExchangeRate].validto))= month(getdate()) THEN NULL
    ELSE pod_eta end AS ArrDate from staging.dutydata i
```

The logic on it is that when ETA is next month and we have exchange rate for next month, then use the ETA, if ETA is next month and we have exchange rate for this month, then null, else use pod_eta (if ETA is this month and we have this month's exchange rate)

MSSQL failes as it can't bind server.database.dbo].CustomsExchangeRate].validto.

They have no common keys I can use to join them...

Comment: Show us some sample table data and also the expected result - all as formatted text, not images! Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before you start.

Comment: how the table  server.database.[dbo].[CustomsExchangeRate]  and  staging.dutydata are related ? .. you are using a table (server.database.[dbo].[CustomsExchangeRate]) not mentioned  in FROM  ..  this i not possible in SQL

Comment: @scaisEdge that is exactly what I am asking.....

Comment: @jarlh sorry but I don't see how the data sample helps on this case. We're looking at dates and the result is a date....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just pull it into a variable.

```
DECLARE @maxMonth int;

SELECT @maxMonth = DATEPART(month,max(validto))
  FROM server.database.[dbo].[CustomsExchangeRate];

SELECT distinct 
case when month(pod_eta)>month(getdate()) AND @maxMonth > month(getdate()) then pod_eta 
     when month(pod_eta)>month(getdate()) AND @maxMonth = month(getdate()) THEN NULL
     ELSE pod_eta end AS ArrDate 
from staging.dutydata i;
```

Though this seems dangerous to me. What happens when it's December and the max valid to date is the following January?

Comment: Thank you! this is what I needed. To be honest I don't think I will need this working for 8 months as I imagine I will have to rewrite most of the code in the next few months due to governmental changes, I will however code a year comparison as well to ensure I don't mess it up :)

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
SELECT  distinct 
CASE WHEN month(pod_eta)>month(getdate()) AND month(max(myServer.validto))> month(getdate()) THEN pod_eta 
WHEN month(pod_eta)>month(getdate()) AND month(max(myServer.validto))= month(getdate()) THEN NULL
ELSE pod_eta END AS ArrDate 
FROM staging.dutydata i, server.database.[dbo].[CustomsExchangeRate] myServer Group by pod_eta
```

Comment: Why are you using 1989 ANSI join syntax here? And do you really want a Cartesian Product of the 2 objects?

Comment: Column 'staging.dutydata.POD_ETA' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.